# Allow users to start/stop particular Azure VMs

Tags: azure

Our sales team will be using Azure VMs to do sales demos. I would like to be able to allow certain people to be able to start/stop their own VMs at will. I've seen being able to add people as an administrator in the management portal, but this seems to give them access to our whole subscription. I'd like to be able to manage this without having everyone create their own subscription.

Example scenario:

Person A is able to start/stop Person A's dedicated VM.

Person B is able to start/stop Person B's dedicated VM. 
etc.

Answer (score 28):

In order to allow a user to start and stop a virtual machine you need to create a custom [role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) with the right permissions.

In this answer I will list the steps to follow in order to get this result using the `Azure Command Line Interface`. You can do the same using the `PowerShell` or the `Azure Rest Api` (find more information about the commands to be used with the `Power Shell` at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell) and with the `Azure Rest Api` at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest)).

- Create a JSON file with the following content (let us name it `newRole.json`):

```json
{
    "Name": "Virtual Machine Operator",
    "IsCustom": true,
    "Description": "Can deallocate, start, and restart virtual machines.",
    "Actions": [
        "Microsoft.Compute/*/read",
        "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action",
        "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action",
        "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action"
    ],
    "NotActions": [],
    "AssignableScopes": [
        "/subscriptions/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
    ]
}
```

- A short explanation of each field of the JSON file:

  - `Name`: the name of the new role. This is the name that will be shown in the Azure Portal
  - `IsCustom`: specifies that it is a user defined role
  - `Description`: a short description of the role, also shown in the Azure Portal
  - `Actions`: the list of actions that can be performed by a user with this role. Each line, respectively, allows the user to:

    - See the list of virtual machines (not all of them, we will see later how to specify which VM will be visible to each user)
    - Start one of the virtual machines among those in the list
    - Restart one of the virtual machines among those in the list
    - Deallocate one of the virtual machines among those in the list
  - `NotActions`: the list of action that can't be performed by a user with this role. In this case the list is empty; in general, it is often a subset of the previous field.
  - `AssignableScopes`: the set of your subscriptions where the role may be added. Each code is prefixed by the `/subscriptions/` string. You can find the code of your subscription by accessing the subscription menu (identified by this icon)

    [image: Azure/Subscriptions]

    and copy the value within the `SUBSCRIPTION ID` field
- Login to your Azure account via the `Azure CLI`. More information about how to install the Azure CLI and perform the login process may be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).
- Create the new role executing the command `az role definition create --role-definition newRole.json`.
- Access the portal and select the virtual machine that has to be powered on and off by a user of your choice.
- After you have selected the machine, select `Access Control (IAM)`.

  [image: Azure/VM/IAM]
- From the new blade select `Add`.
- Fill in the fields as follows:

  - `Role`: Select the role you just created -- in our case, `Virtual Machine Operator`
  - `Assign access to`: `Azure AD user, group, or application`.
  - `Select`: the email associated to the account that needs to start/restart/stop the VM.
- Select `Save`.

After this operation, when the user accesses the Azure Portal, they will see the selected VM in the list of the virtual machines. Upon selecting the virtual machine, they will be able to start/restart/stop it.

Comment: This works well, but for a VM-operator they might benefit from additional permissions (e.g. this role won't let the Operator see the machines public IP). Microsoft has a tutorial here with Virtual Machine Operator as the specific example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles#custom-role-example

Comment: `Microsoft.Compute/*/read` gives the user read access to a lot more than just the basic VM properties (which is required to see the Stop/Start buttons). They get read access to disks, images, galleries, host groups, restore points, etc. A better permission would be `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read`.

Answer (score 11):

Open your VM in portal.azure.com
navigate to `Access control (IAM)` → `Role Assignments` and click Add Role Assignment.

Select standard role *Virtual Machine Contributor*,

*Assign access to* leave by default (Azure AD user, group ...),

In *Select* field enter email of new limited user and select Guest.

Save.

That's all.
[image]

Comment: Consider that this solution gives much more access to the employee other than allowing to start/stop the VM. The _Virtual Machine Contributor_ role also allows to modify the availability sets, disks, vm and network configuration, vaults, protection policies, etc. While this role does technically answer the question about start/stop VM, I understand from the OP that the employees are not no change the VMs, they just need to be able to start/stop them so they can use them.

Answer (score 5):

Ive created a custom role to allow this. I've tested and it works.
You have to start with the "Virtual Machine User Login" role then add the additional permissions. This does of course give the user log permissions as well but I assume if you are allowing them to start and stop the VM then you would also want them the ability to log in.

Via the GUI:

```
 1. Add Custom Role
 2. Select "Clone a role" and role to close is "Virtual Machine User Login"
 3. Click Next
 4. Select add permissions
 5. Scroll  down to "Microsoft.Compute.VirtualMachines" and tick
Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action"
"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/powerOff/action"
"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action"
 6. Click Next, select subscription, Next, Next then "Create".
 7. List item
```

### All permissions for the role:

- Action   Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read
- Action   Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read
- Action   Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read
- Action   Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/read
- Action   Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/read
- Action   Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/*/read
- Action   Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action
- Action   Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/powerOff/action
- Action   Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action
- DataAction   Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/login/action

### Here's the JSON:

`{ "properties": { "roleName": "VM_Operator_test", "description": "", "assignableScopes": [ "/subscriptions/exampesubscription/EXAMPLE_RG" ], "permissions": [ { "actions": [ "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read", "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/read", "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/read", "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/*/read", "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action", "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/powerOff/action", "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action" ], "notActions": [], "dataActions": [ "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/login/action" ], "notDataActions": [] } ] }}`

Answer (score 2):

**Through [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/)**

1. Create a custom-role file `VirtualMachineStartStop.json`:

   ```json
   {
       "Name": "Virtual Machine Start Stop Access",
       "IsCustom": true,
       "Description": "Start/Restart/Deallocate virtual machines",
       "Actions": [
           "Microsoft.Storage/*/read",
           "Microsoft.Network/*/read",
           "Microsoft.Compute/*/read",
           "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action",
           "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action",
           "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action"
       ],
       "NotActions": [],
       "AssignableScopes": [
           "/subscriptions/<azure_subscription_id_here>"
       ] 
   }
   ```
2. Create role:

   ```
   az role definition create --role-definition "./VirtualMachineStartStop.json"
   ```
3. Confirm the role creation:

   ```
   az role definition list --custom-role-only true
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible. Though it is possible via some programming. What you see on Azure Portal can be achieved through [`Azure Service Management API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx). What you could do is write an application which consumes this API and there you could define all the rules.

If you think your sales folks will not mess around, another thing you could do is create some custom PowerShell scripts by making use of [`Azure PowerShell Cmdlets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156055.aspx) and they can just execute those scripts to start/stop the VMs.

Comment: I agree with the Azure Powershell Cmdlets. Had been testing them out yesterday. However, how would I go about getting their users authenticated in Windows Azure Powershell? Do I still need to add them as administrators in the management portal?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to build your own façade that leverages the Azure Management API to perform these tasks for you. This allows you to put in place your own controls around access/authorization as well as rig it to span multiple subscriptions (should this ever prove necessary). This façade could potentially be hosted in a free tier Azure web site.

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot create custom roles, you now have the "Desktop Virtualization Power On Off Contributor" role; which can both start and stop the Virtual Machine (VM). There is also the "
Desktop Virtualization Power On Contributor" role which can only start the VM.

You can assign this in the CLI with the command below with the necessary placeholders filled in;

```
az role assignment create \
  --assignee *userObjectId* \
  --role "Desktop Virtualization Power On Off Contributor" \
  --scope "/subscriptions/*Your Subscription ID*/resourceGroups/*YourResourceGroup*/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/*YourVirtualMachineName*"
```

You will need to substitute SubscriptionId, ResourceGroupName, VirtualMachineName and also userObjectId which you can get from the query below.

```
az ad user show --id "user@example.com" --query objectId --output tsv
```